# Raspbian Stretch lite doesnt send HDMI signal on second boot

Tags: boot, hdmi, signal

I have installed the most recent Raspbian Stretch lite (release: 2018-11-13) to a SanDisk ultra A1 micro SD card to use it for my Raspberry Pi model 3B. I connected a HDMI monitor and a USB keyboard to it.

The first Time I boot up the Raspberry Pi, everything works just fine. The Pi boots and I can use the keyboard and the monitor.

But when I shutdown the RaspberryPi with `sudo shutdown -h now` after the first successful boot with a working monitor, and try to start it up again with "*unplug and plug in power connection*", the Pi will still boot, but my monitor doesnt receive any HDMI signal anymore. Apparently the keyboard doesn´t work too, because the caps lock control light doesn´t shine. From now on, I can only use the Pi with PuTTY via SSH.

I have tried to reflash Raspbian again and I get the same issue again. The first time, monitor and keyboard are working, and after that I am limited to PuTTY only.

I have also added the `hdmi_safe=1` tag inside the `/boot/config.txt` but that didn´t change anything.

**The question is:** Is there something else I have to change in the settings, to enable the monitor to work every time since it is the Raspbian version without a desktop? Or is the problem somewhere else and if so, where?

Any help is appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**
I just found out, that:

- I only get a HDMI signal the very first time I plug in power
- after I `sudo shutdown -h now` and booting the Pi with a power cycle, I won´t get a HDMI signal, I´m limitet to PuTTY, but: If I then then type `sudo reboot`  over the SSH connection to start the Pi without a power cycle, I do receive a HDMI signal again.

Comment: So, all you do is flash, boot (which does a reboot anyway after expanding filesystem) - then next time you boot, nothing works? You don't make ANY changes whatsoever and always the third boot keyboard and display fail? (I say third, as there is a reboot as I said on first boot - so that's two boot that work)

Comment: No, I forgot to say that this apears when I want to start the Pi with unplug the power connection and plug it in again. On the first successful boot I can reboot the Pi via `reboot` command as often as I want to and I receive a HDMI signal every time afterwards. In short: after the `sudo shutdown -h now` command and starting it again with "unplug plug in power" I get this error. Thx for the comment, I will try to make my question a bit more clear.

Comment: my comment was to ascertain that you don't change a single thing ... you just power cycle

Answer (score 3):

**Common Hack**

I have had that kinda problem, pi is booting but nothing appeared on the monitor or sometime flashes after intervals. after searching out, someone mentioned there that it might possible you're not supplying the enough power.

I was providing 5.1 A after changing to 5.2 A. boom i got the my screen back. i'm not sure about this hack but it solved my problem back there.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, this works fine for me with a Dell monitor, so it's not a broad Raspbian problem.

Have you tried power-cycling the monitor at those times when you do a shutdown -h now? I'm wondering if there's some stray HDMI signal as the Pi shuts down that confuses your monitor.

Comment: I have tried what you said, and even though I had no success  I noticed that other monitors work fine. My monitor is from Dell too, seems like its a monitor related problem.